# Graph Editor not working properly

Tags: graph-editor

What the Graph editor is no showing the rotation paths.

1. Object is selected.
2. Only show selected key map handlers is disabled.

[image: My workflow]

https://pasteall.org/blend/a3c3e6741ae145109bb7d9fb7ca885e4

Comment: hello could you please share your file (copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the Z Euler rotation channel, then press the "Home" key to reveal the curve (or go to Graph editor Menu > View > Frame All).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what you mean, but if you click on that little triangle there beside "object transform":

[image]

you will get:

[image]